# Sub-optimal queries over many-to-many relations with HQL

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, hql

I have two entities, Location and Industry, and a link-table between them. I've configured a many-to-many relationship, in both directions, between the two entities.

In a search query, I'm trying to select Locations that are associated with a list of industries.

After days and days of trying to wrangle the criteria API, I've decided to drop down to HQL and abandon the criteria API. But even that isn't going well for me - it seems, regardless of whether I hand-write this HQL query, or let the criteria API do it, I end up with the same result.

I managed to produce the right result in two ways - like this:

```
var q = Data.Query("select distinct loc from Location loc join loc.Industries ind where ind in (:ind)");

q.SetParameterList("ind", new Industry[] { Data.GetIndustry(4), Data.GetIndustry(5) });
```

And (better) like that:

```
var q = Data.Query("select distinct loc from Location loc join loc.Industries ind where ind.id in (:ind)");

q.SetParameterList("ind", new int[] { 4, 5 });
```

Unfortunately, both result in a sub-optimal query:

```
select distinct
  location0_.Id as Id16_,
  location0_.Name as Name16_,
  (etc.)
from Location location0_
  inner join LocationIndustry industries1_
    on location0_.Id=industries1_.LocationId
  inner join Industry industry2_
    on industries1_.IndustryId=industry2_.Id
where
  industry2_.Id in (? , ?)
```

Why the extra join?

Is NH not smart enough to know that the Industry.Id property, being the only Industry-property involved in the query, is stored in the LocationIndustry link-table, and there is no need for the extra join to the Industry table itself?

Or am I doing something wrong?

Ideally, the most intuitive thing for me would be to write:

```
from Location loc where loc.Industries in (:ind)
```

This does not work - it throws an error and says it does not know about the Industries property. I guess because Industries, being a "property" in programming terms, is actually a "relationship" in terms of DBMS.

What is the simplest and most efficient way to write this query in HQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question. Have you measured a significant difference between the queries with or without the extra join, though? And maybe it does the extra join to handle the case where there is no foreign key constraint in the join table and some record reference non-existing industries?

Comment: That's one possible explanation, although it seems like a poor work-around to account for inconsistent data that should not be present in a well-designed and properly maintained database to begin with. Seems more likely this is simply an optimization that just hasn't been implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can avoid this extra join given the mapping strategy you have used.

You could avoid it by using an intermediary class but this would mean you would need a class structure like this:

```
public class Industry {
    //Other stuff
    public virtual List<LocationIndustry> LocationIndustries {get; set:;}
}

public class LocationIndustry {
    public virtual Location Location {get; set;}
    public virtual Industry Industry {get; set;}
}

public class Location {
    //normal stuff
    public virtual IList<LocationIndustry> LocationIndustries {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can query on the `LocationIndustry` class and avoid the join to `Location`.

Comment: +1 and thanks, but I already considered this option, and I find it ugly - I don't want to warp the domain model and introduce useless entities; it also means I have to manage more objects and maintain twice as many relationships when associations are added/removed. (I'm starting to think that even a monster like NH can't deal with all the aspects of impedance mismatch...)

Comment: Indeed, this is one of those situations where you are trading performance for flexibility. Can you live with a SQLQuery or a Named Query in this circumstance? You can write the query in SQL and still map it to objects.

Comment: If you are usung nh3.1 you could of used the new `with` syntax on the hql to add the in clause to the join. However this is bugged when in comes to using it with many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions - I will accept your answer, since there is clearly no better way to do this with NH. Personally, I have decided to live with the extra join and not worry about it unless it becomes necessary to optimize it away - I don't want to complicate the software to try to accommodate the ORM.